# Prob. 9, Sec. 3.2 in Erwine Kreyszig's "Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications"

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

Here is Prob. 9 in the Problems after Sec. 3.2 in *Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications* by Erwine Kreyszig:

> Let $V$ be the vector space of all continuous complex-valued functions on $J = [a,b]$. Let $X_1 = \left( V, \Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty \right)$, where $\Vert x \Vert_\infty = \max_{t \in J} \vert x(t) \vert$; and let $X_2 = \left( V, \Vert \cdot \Vert_2 \right)$, where 
>   $$\Vert x \Vert_2 = \langle x, x \rangle^{1/2}, \ \ \ \ \langle x, y \rangle \ = \ \int_a^b \ x(t) \overline{y(t)} \ \mathrm{d} t. 
> $$
>   Show that the identity mapping $x \mapsto x$ of $X_1$ onto $X_2$ is continuous. ...

My Solution:

For any $x, y \in V$, we have 
$$
\begin{align*}
\Vert x-y \Vert_2^2 \ &= \ \int_a^b \ \vert x(t) - y(t) \vert^2 \ \mathrm{d} t \\ 
&\leq \ \int_a^b \ \max_{s \in J} \vert x(s) - y(s) \vert^2 \ \mathrm{d} t \\ 
&= \ \int_a^b \ \left( \max_{s \in J} \vert x(s) - y(s) \vert \right)^2 \ \mathrm{d} t  \ \ \ \mbox{ [Is this step justified, I wonder?]} \\ 
&= \ \left( \max_{s \in J} \vert x(s) - y(s) \vert \right)^2 \ \int_a^b \ \mathrm{d} t  \\
&= \Vert x-y \Vert_\infty^2 (b-a);
\end{align*}
$$
so 
$$
\Vert x-y \Vert_2 \leq \Vert x-y \Vert_\infty \sqrt{b-a}.
$$
So, given $\epsilon > 0$, if we choose $\delta$ such that $0 < \delta < \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{b-a}}$, then 
$$
\Vert x-y \Vert_2 < \epsilon
$$
for all $x, y \in V$ such that 
$$
\Vert x-y \Vert_\infty < \delta,
$$
showing that the identity map is even uniformly continuous.

Is the above proof correct?

If so, then how to show directly if the inverse map is also continuous or not?

Comment: That intermediate step is redundant, as you suspected. The proof is correct. The statement essentially tells you that if the sequence $f_n$ tends **uniformly** to $f$, then the integrals of $f_n$ will tend to the integral of $f$.

Comment: If you instead note that $|x-y| \le \|x-y\|_{\infty}$, then the steps become more obvious. The max operator can be confusing.

Comment: your proof is correct but notice one thing that proceeding the same way as you did you can show that $\|x\|_2\leq \sqrt{b-a}\|x\|_{\infty}$ for all $x \in X_1$. So you are done here as this shows that the identity operator is bounded and hence continuous.